# Dynamic namespaced class with alias

Tags: php, namespaces

SO,

I have an issue with dynamic object creation using namespaces. 
Here's namespace code:

```
namespace Foo
{
   class Bar
   {
   }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to create object of class `Bar` with:

```
include('namespace.php');
$sName  = 'Bar';
$sClass = '\\Foo\\'.$sName;
$rObj   = new $sClass; //correct object
```

and everything going well with that. But, now I want to use alias and doing something like:

```
include('namespace.php');
use Foo as Baz;
$sName  = 'Bar';
$sClass0= '\\Foo\\'.$sName;
$sClass1= '\\Baz\\'.$sName;
$rObj   = new $sClass0; //correct object
$rObj   = new $sClass1; //Fatal error
```

And I'm unable to instantiate an object such way (and accessing via full name still works well). 
So, my question is - is it possible to access the class via alias somehow, and, if yes, how?  I've also tried to access when using `$sClass1='Baz\\'.$sName` - no success. Also, I've checked declared classes via `get_declared_classes()` function, it shows that I have only `\Foo\Bar` class (no reference to an alias).

*I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm using PHP 5.5 version.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the parser uses your namespace aliases to canonicalize the class references inside each of your files.

In other words, it doesn't introduce some kind of global alias that other code can use. Once your script has been parsed, the alias is no longer used.

This behaviour is also described in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#example-247):

> Importing is performed at compile-time, and so does not affect dynamic class, function or constant names.

Comment: Wanted to answer the same, aliasing is compile time. The variable and the class name is run-time, so it needs your own runtime aliasing, like replacing in classname string via some creator/factory function/method.

Comment: It seems I've misunderstood architecture of aliasing at this point, thanks.

Comment: @Alma Do Mundo: This happens to the best of us because namespaces in PHP are actually pretty limited. There is a good summary here: [PHP namespaces are flawed (Aug 2011; by poneL)](http://pornel.net/phpns)

Comment: Well, it shows some insight. It's not that I agree with all the arguments given, but it gives a good overview. Especially the point about reserved keywords is interesting to know about. It's another common problem you can run into when using PHP namespaces.