# Unrecognized namespace alias causing unexpected invocation of autoloader

Tags: php, namespaces

I am attempting use a namespace alias to invoke static behavior on a class. The class has already been loaded, and I think I've got its alias defined properly. When I attempt to use that alias, however, php attempts (and fails) to autoload the class. I'm running php 5.3.3, and ZendFramework 1.8.4, all under CentOS 5.9.

Am I doing something wrong?

Here's are some (sanitized) code excerpts (my employer won't allow me to share the actual code, sorry).

```
<?php
// Filename = 'SomeAssembly/AbstractFoo.php'
namespace SomeAssembly;
use BaseAssembly\Base;
use SomeAssembly\ConcreteFoo;

require_once 'BaseAssembly/Base.php';
require_once 'SomeAssembly/ConcreteFoo.php';

class AbstractFoo extends Base {
  // ...
  static public function buildFooNamed_($aFooName) {
    // ...
    $declaredClasses = get_declared_classes();
    $namespace = __NAMESPACE __;
    $answer = $aFooName::create(); // Invokes autoloader!
    return $answer;
  }
}
?>
```

When I invoke AbstractFoo::buildFooNamed_('ConcreteFoo'), the autoloader is invoked. It fails because "ConcreteFoo" does not include the namespace.

When I set a breakpoint at "$answer = $aFooName::create", I see that $declaredClasses includes 'SomeAssembly\ConcreteFoo' and $namespace = 'SomeAssembly".

I think I declared the namespace alias "ConcreteFoo" in the line that reads "use SomeAssembly\ConcreteFoo".

Why isn't "ConcreteFoo" recognized as a namespace alias of a loaded class? If so, why is the autoloader being invoked?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my question has been answered in [Dynamic namespaced class with alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318582/dynamic-namespaced-class-with-alias?rq=1).

From the manual:

> Importing is performed at compile-time, and so does not affect dynamic class, function or constant names.

So I have to collect the fully-qualified class name myself. Oh well.