# getting Classes from variables in namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to update my project with namespaces.
Before using namespaces I could easily call a class via a variable like so:

```
<?php
    $className = "Item";
    $myClass = new $className();
?>
```

Now, when using namespaces (with `use`) I'd expect this to work:
(not working allways meens: 'Can't find class' or smth like this)

```
<?php
    namespace myProject
    use myProject\Models

    $className = "Item";
    $myClass = new $className();   // this class has the namespace myProject\Models
    // this doesn't work! (can't find class)
    $myClass = new Models\$className();
    // nope, doesn't work either
    $myClass = new myProject\Models\$className();
    // nope
?>
```

but calling the same class directly - without a variable - IS working

```
$myClass = new Item();
```

What I have to do, *to make it work* is:

```
<?php
    namespace myProject;
    use myProject\Models;   // unnessecary now

    $className = "\\" . __NAMESPACE__ . "\\Models\\" . "Item";
    $myClass = new $className(); 
?>
```

**My question now is:**
If I want to call a class via a variable, do I really have to include the whole namespace as a *fully qualified name*?

**EDIT**:
I found myself an answer here:
[Dynamic namespaced class with alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318582/dynamic-namespaced-class-with-alias)
I'll keep that question anyway, because I could not find the right answer in first place.

Comment: Actually the solution that you've linked addresses a different issue: using aliases with dynamic namespaces.

But anyway, the anser is yes, you have to include the fully qualified namespace. It says so in the manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php
_"One must use the fully qualified name (class name with namespace prefix)."_